# Binding to a List<string> using DataBinder.Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, databinder

I have the following object:

```
CrossTabDataObject
{
   string RowName{get;set;};
   int RowId{get;set;}
   List<string> CellContents = new List <string>();
   //Constructor..... etc.

}
```

I'm building a dynamic crosstab grid using GridView in asp.net 3.5

I wish to bind to CellContents[0] for dynamic column 1, CellContents[1] for dynamic column 2 (dynamic column 0 is the RowName field from the CrossTabDataObject) etc. I am using:

```
object boundValueObj = null;
Control ctrl = (Control)sender;
IDataItemContainer dataItemContainer = (IDataItemContainer)ctrl.NamingContainer;
boundValueObj = DataBinder.Eval(dataItemContainer.DataItem, strSelectedID);
```

This code is in the InstantiateIn function of the gridview as I'm creating drop down list templates in each cell of the crosstab.

I have code (not shown) that sets strSelectedID depending on the column being created.

When strSelectedID is equal to "RowName" for dynamic column [0] the DataBinder.Eval function works fine and sets boundValueObj as expected. The problem comes when strSelectedID is set to "CellContents[n]" where n is the Column Index.

DataBinder.Eval only works with properties and fields of objects. How do I get around this?

Thanks,

Rich.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - stupid mistake by me!

Changing:

```
CrossTabDataObject
{
   string RowName{get;set;};
   int RowId{get;set;}
   List<string> CellContents = new List <string>();
   //Constructor..... etc.

}
```

to:

```
CrossTabDataObject
{
   string RowName{get;set;};
   int RowId{get;set;}
   List<string> CellContents{get;set;}
   //Constructor
   public CrossTabDataObject()
   {
     CellContents = new List<string>();
   }

}
```

made all the difference. In other words I made CellContents a property of the class.

Rich.